# Можно ли использовать Google Play Console в 15 лет

Tags: google-play

Я создаю игру под андроид и хочу опубликовать ее google play, но у меня возник вопрос. Можно ли создавать аккаунт Google play console если нет 18 лет? Карта и паспорт есть.

Comment: Вы про это? https://play.google.com/about/console/terms-of-service/: "К использованию Play Console допускаются только лица, достигшие 18 лет, а также возраста совершеннолетия в Вашей стране, позволяющего заключить юридически обязательный договор с Google."

Comment: Никто возраст не спрашивал у меня

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, но если у вас указанно в аккаунте что вам **больше** **18**. Попробуйте изменить возраст в настройках аккаунта **если там меньше 18**. И тогда можно загружать.